# Drop databases with no tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there a query which drops / deletes databases with no tables in them (deletes empty databases)?

Server is Microsoft SQL Server 2005

Comment: Sql Shell would be my option.

Comment: see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47726/how-to-query-a-database-for-empty-tables.  Then just drop the tables whose names are returned.

Comment: @DanRitchie that's not really what the OP was looking for.... We're talking databases, not tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.
Tested on a lab machine and it dropped all databases with 0 user tables.
Note, however, that tables aren't the only things in a database, necessarily.  There could be stored procedures, functions, etc that someone might still need.

NOTE THAT THIS IS A VERY DANGEROUS OPERATION, AS IT DROPS DATABASES. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK. I AM NOT RESPONSIBLE FOR DAMAGE YOU CAUSE.

```
USE [master];
DECLARE @name varchar(50);
DECLARE @innerQuery varchar(max);
DECLARE tableCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM sys.databases where owner_sid != 0x01;
OPEN tableCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM tableCursor
INTO @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @innerQuery = 'USE [' + @name + ']; IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.objects WHERE type = ''U'') = 0
    BEGIN
        USE [master];
        DROP DATABASE [' + @name + ']
    END'
    EXEC(@innerQuery)
    FETCH NEXT FROM tableCursor INTO @name
END

CLOSE tableCursor;
DEALLOCATE tableCursor;
```

Note also that, if a database is in use, SQL Server will refuse to drop it.  So, if there are other connections to a particular database that this tries to drop, the command will abort.

To avoid that problem, you can set the database in question to single-user mode.

The following script is the same as the above, except it also sets the target databases to single-user mode to kill active connections.
BE EVEN MORE CAREFUL WITH THIS, AS IT'S ESSENTIALLY THE NUCLEAR OPTION:

```
use [master];
DECLARE @name varchar(50);
DECLARE @innerQuery varchar(max);
DECLARE tableCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM sys.databases where owner_sid != 0x01;
OPEN tableCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM tableCursor
INTO @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @innerQuery = 
    'USE [' + @name + '];
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.objects WHERE type = ''U'') = 0
    BEGIN
        USE [master];
        ALTER DATABASE [' + @name + '] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
        DROP DATABASE [' + @name + '];
    END'
    EXEC(@innerQuery)
    FETCH NEXT FROM tableCursor INTO @name
END

CLOSE tableCursor;
DEALLOCATE tableCursor;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible (at least not with a TSQL command, might be a stored procedure somewhere). You would have to query `sysobjects` and abort if any found. (And you have to decide if you want to ignore some of the system objects like the design tables).

Answer (score 0):

The script below will generate the needed DROP DATABASE script.  You could tweak this to execute the statement too (in the master database context) but I suggest you review it first just in case.

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb N'
    USE [?];
    IF N''?'' NOT IN(N''master'', N''model'', N''msdb'', N''tempdb'')
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT *
            FROM sys.tables
            WHERE
                OBJECTPROPERTYEX(object_id, ''IsMSShipped'') = 0
            )
        BEGIN
            PRINT ''DROP DATABASE [?];'';
        END;
    END;';
```